# WSO2 SAP endpoint property file - searching for wrong file name and path

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, jco, sapjco3

I have "export" proxy service which aims to "obtain" sequence. The sequence points to `${server}/services/sapBapi` or "sapBapi" proxy service. The "sapBapi" proxy service points to `gov:endpoints/sapbapiendpoint.xml` endpoint, where is the concrete address: `bapi:/abc`

I have abc.dest and abc.server property files with SAP endpoint parameters on path
`$WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/sap` according to official documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/SAP+Integration)

When I want to use "export" proxy service and send data, I will find this in logs:

> DEBUG - Started sending message to uri=bapi:/abc/services/sapBapi/services/export {org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender}
> WARN - JCo configuration file for the destination : abc/services/sapBapi/services/export  does not exist - Please specify the JCo configuration in $WSO2_HOME/conf/sap/abc/services/sapBapi/services/export.dest or abc/services/sapBapi/services/export.dest {org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.CarbonDestinationDataProvider}
> ERROR - Error while sending request to the EPRbapi:/abc/services/sapBapi/services/export {org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender}
> com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Destination abc/services/sapBapi/services/export does not exist

When I put `export.dest` file to path `$WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/sap/abc/services/sapBapi/services/`, then it works perfectly.

My questions:

1. Why is it using proxy service name ("export") for the .dest property
   file in described case?
2. Why is it searching for .dest property file
   on path `$WSO2_HOME/conf/sap/abc/services/sapBapi/services/` instead
   of `$WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/sap/`?

WSO2 version: 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WSO2 Enterprise Integrator, but obviously an instance of class `org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.CarbonDestinationDataProvider` is the registered `DestinationDataProvider` at the JCo runtime. This is the instance that decides alone from where to obtain the logon parameters for a `JCoDestination` based on the destination name string that it gets from the `JCoDestinationManager`.

From your example error message, this destination name string seems to be *"abc/services/sapBapi/services/export"* in this case for which the `org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.CarbonDestinationDataProvider` is searching a property file with name *abc/services/sapBapi/services/export.dest*

I hope this info will help you to adapt your code/configuration to fit your expectations.